# XOR image decryption

Tags: python

I made program which encrypts and decrypts image using XOR encryption. However, my image after decryption isn't the same and i don't know why. Can you tell me what am i doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

[image: original]
[image: after decryption]

```
def decode(key):
    from PIL import Image
    from tqdm import tqdm

    def xor_encrypting(color_in: str, key_in: str):
        if color_in == key_in:
            return '0'
        else:
            return '1'



    img=Image.open('secret.jpg')
    width = int(img.width)
    height = int(img.height)
    pixel_map = img.load()


    pos = 0

    for i in tqdm(range(width),'decode'):
        for j in range(height):
            r, g, b = img.getpixel((i, j))
            color = bin(r)[2:].zfill(8) + bin(g)[2:].zfill(8) + bin(b)[2:].zfill(8)
            key24 = key[pos:pos+24]
            d = 0

            # making key for 1 pixel
            if len(key) != 24:
                if len(key) > 24:
                    key24 = key[pos:pos+24]
                    pos += 24
                    if len(key24) < 24:
                        pos = 0
                        while len(key24) < 24:
                            key24 = key24 + key[pos]
                            pos += 1

                # repet too short key
                while len(key24) < 24:
                    if d >= len(key)-1:
                        d = 0
                    key24 = key24 + key[d]
                    d += 1

            # decode
            new_color = ''
            for k in range(24):
                new_color += xor_encrypting(color[k], key24[k])

            pixel_map[i, j] = (int(new_color[0:8], 2), int(
                new_color[8:16], 2), int(new_color[16:24], 2))

    print(len(color))
    img.show()
    return pixel_map
```

Comment: Please explain how your encryption algorithm works, we shouldn't have to figure it out from uncommented code.

Comment: my encryption algorithm take rgb of every pixel change it to binary and do xor operation with every bit of rgb and key.        
 if color_in == key_in:
            return '0'
        else:
            return '1'